# Fullwidth website with vertically split background

Tags: html, css

I am implementing a website which have a layout like below

[image: layout]

I am a bit confuse about the HTML structure for this layout blue section is almost half divide my background and content will be centered and blue section will always be exactly divided in this ratio can anyone assist me how to make it possible. One more thing I need to use blue section as background color may be in RGBA.

Comment: I dont write my code according to it because i couldnt get the right way doing that and that is what i am asking here html structure

Comment: Where will the copy/content be placed, over the blue overlay panel or over the entire width of the image/overlay section?

Comment: that will be center container to both the parts like the menu is centered you can see in the image

Comment: #Marc I once did that with -9999 method may be uknow about it but now o forget how to do that and i couldnt find any support for that technique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pseudo-element could work here

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-100-100-9.jpg);
}
body::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  z-index: -1;
}
.navbar {
  margin-top: 25px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar"></div>
```

Comment: #Paulie its not working with z-index:-1; and when i put z-index:1 it works but then it also come over the content as well

Comment: Obviously **my** demo does but if you have actual code I suggest you ask a separate question with your own demo. You could always give your content a higher z-index though.

Answer (score 0):

Place this DIV after body tag:

```
<body>
     <div id="blue"></div>
           content
</body>

body {
 background:url('img');
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 }
#blue {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 50%;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.35);
 height: 100%;
 width: 1000px;
 }
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/o4tc7wvs/)

Comment: Martin this wont be a good approach when you need to make the site responsive as absolute position dive will go out of the container